# HTML 5 Section and Main semantic tags use

Tags: html, semantic-markup

While studying the HTML 5 semantic tags, I've ran upon some doubts on how to proper utilize the *main* and *section* tags, and since the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) reference seems a little vague and other references on the Web seems to diverge I would like to know if there is a proper guideline to the following questions or if its pretty much up to the programmer:

1. Does the *main* tag also has the meaning of grouping related elements or in that case should it be within a *section* tag?
2. Does it make sense to wrap single elements, such as an image, into a *section* tag?
3. It's pretty common to have a *header* and *footer* of the page (not inside any section), in that case, should the remaining in between those tags be wrapped inside a *section* tag, as if delimiting the "content" of the page?

Comment: A section element should be semantically standalone. Therefore logically a section shouldn't be 'tied' to the specific page (although in practice they often are). Sections should therefore have their own element hierarchy such that they could in theory be 'lifted and shifted' elsewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the main tag also has the meaning of grouping related elements

Only to the same extent that `<div>` groups related elements. The primary purpose of `<main>` is to indicate where the dominant content of the page starts. (and additionally, according to the WHATWG spec but not the W3C one, where the dominant content of the page *resumes*).

> or in that case should it be within a section tag?

A section tag is one way of grouping your content, to indicate that its contents are on a particular theme, in a way that differs from the content which is not in the section. Typically, you can and should give the section a heading using a `<h[1-6]>` element, which states what that theme is.

> Does it make sense to wrap single elements, such as an image, into a
>   section tag?

Rarely. For one thing that would mean that the section didn't contain a heading. See above. It's unlikely that any new information would be conveyed by wrapping an image on its own in a section tag.

> It's pretty common to have a header and footer of the page (not inside
>   any section), in that case, should the remaining in between those tags
>   be wrapped inside a section tag, as if delimiting the "content" of the
>   page?

No. The "content" of the section is the section less its header and footer. There's no need to add another sectioning element container.